# StreamReader posting in an Textbox with delay

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, streamreader

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Files.txt");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Copying: " + line;
    counter++;
}
```

I have this Code to read an textfile with multiple paths in it. What i want to do is to post them in a textbox which I got so far, but my question is can i do a 1sec delay between each line the streamreader is going to post?

Comment: Sry forgot that it is windows form

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000);` ...?

Comment: @sab669 why suggest something that will simply lead to "why my UI is frozen"?

Comment: I tried thread sleep but it just says thread doesn't exist in that context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720319/timer-in-winforms has both timer-based and async/await solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something of this sort:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) =>
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Files.txt");
    string line;
    int counter = 0;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Copying: " + line;
            }));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        counter++;
    }
});
```

Alternatively as suggested in comments above, a `BackgroundWorker` could also be used.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I will try this later, have some other work to do. I will give you some feedback then

Answer (score 0):

1) Use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

*Implements a timer that raises an event at user-defined intervals. This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must be used in a window.*

2) Read all lines in Queue.

```
Queue<string> lines = new Queue<string>( File.ReadAllLines( @"Path" ) );
```

3) Use timer event to read per line in List.

```
private void Timer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( lines.Count > 0 )
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Copying: " + lines.Dequeue();
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Check for empty [Queue.Dequeue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.queue.dequeue(v=vs.110).aspx) ( `lines.Count > 0` or another, stop timer when it's become true)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the System.Threading class to call: `Thread.Sleep(1000);` once per loop iteration.

More information on the System.Threading class at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT:

As mentioned below, using Thread.Sleep causes the UI to lock up during the Sleep method. As an alternative, you may like to try the [BackgroundWorker class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

The following snippet assumes you want to trigger your code above from a button click (it was unclear from the question whether this is actually the case or not).

```
private void startAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(backgroundWorkerA.IsBusy != true)
   {
      //start the Async Thread
      backgroundWorkerA.RunWorkerAsync();
   }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Files.txt");

   while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Copying: " + line;
       counter++;
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

Here you are simply creating a worker thread to do the (relatively) time-consuming task without tying up your GUI.

Comment: As Alexei points out, this will cause the UI to freeze for a second at a time. If you do not want such functionality, I suggest investigating the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: You *should not* use `Thread.Sleep` on UI thread. Doing so on non-UI thread requires much more code than shown so far in this post.

Comment: Yeah just found out that my ui dies

Comment: @Ayres see above for edited answer including BackgroundWorker information.