# How to make a fade in/fade out animation for a customMessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, animation, fadein, fadeout

I made a custom MessageBox in Visual Studio 2013; Language: C# 4.5, So I want that messageBox to appear with a fade in effect and disappear with fadeOut when I click on either Cancel or Ok button. I did this but with a pictureBox, and I'm stuck on how to make it work with a messageBox.

**Note: This is not in WPF, just C# WinForm**

Thanks in Advance - CCB

Comment: Are you using WinForms and is this custom message box based on a `Window`?

Comment: It is a Widows Form without border.

Comment: Probably best to use a library like this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548769/Animator-for-WinForms but if you wanna do it by hand, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497826/better-algorithm-to-fade-a-winform

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss have you done a google search on `Opacity` there are  several working examples on the web

Comment: Oh ok, I'll try that library. Thanks, I didn't see that post before. I'll share the results later.

Comment: @MickaelV. I like the animations that the Animator for WinForms offers, how can I use it? I have to add the .cs source to my project? 'Cause it says to drag the component Animator to my Form, but it does not appear any component called "Animator"

Comment: I guess you can either download the demo and take the DLL that comes with it, or download the sources and compile the DLL. Either way it's a little out of the scope of this SO question